# Constructing the Von Neuman Hierarchy at ω+ω in a structural set theory

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I'm working in [SEAR](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR) which is a relatively new structural set theory, and I am trying to prove the existence of big sets.

SEAR has the collection axiom which is, loosely speaking, that for every formula that describes an indexed family of sets, we get that family reified as a characterizing set which is isomorphic to the index set and has a one-to-many relation into a big set that represents the disjoint union of all the sets in the family.

Now, it is simple enough to make $V_\omega$: we identify the natural number 0 with the empty set, and every other natural number with the powerset of its predecessor's set. Working with the resulting set formally is a little awkward.

As far as I can understand, in order to get $V_{\omega+\omega}$, we just repeat the process with 0 identified with $V_\omega$. Is that correct?

ETA: Upon further consideration, the construction of $V_\omega$ may be relatively unimportant in SEAR, seeing as it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$. Question still stands: collecting over $\mathbb N$, with 0 identified with $\mathbb N$ and successors identified with powersets of predecessors, do we get $V_{\omega + \omega}$?

Comment: Your link of SEAR links to the power object page on nlab.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oops! fixed! Gotta be careful what I have in the cipboard.